# Java storing byte[] in static Map on a Web app - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java

Is it a bad practice to store `byte[]` in a map as such

`static LinkedHashMap<String, byte[]> fileBuffer = new LinkedHashMap<>()`?

When my class is unloaded profiler still shows persitent `byte[]` memory usage.

Eventually `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown after several hours.

Does `jvm` (Oracle jdk8u121) have some prejudice regarding map GC?

***Some context***: A dynamic custom report tool using Oracle jobs on a server.

Comment: Well if you're never letting the map get garbage collected, and keep adding more entries to it, then sure, that's going to be a problem...

Comment: can GC be forced, or at least hinted? But that is again bad practice innit

Comment: I dont store over 10 files per report in memory, so per session usage shouldn't be high

Comment: We have no idea what "files" or "reports" you're talking about - you've basically given us almost no context here. What are you doing to clear entries out of the map?

Comment: @publicinformation do you ever remove the `byte[]` from that map?

Comment: yes, explicit map.clear() method on in try-catch-finally

Comment: MS Office files, .zip, .txt, .pdf files on windows machines

Comment: Start the jvm so that it creates a heapdump when `OutOfMemoryError`s occur. The heapdump should have some information on who is holding the references.

Comment: will attach a dump in several hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best bet is that you never clear your map, or you are never making ig garbage collectable prevending it from beeing garbage collected. Map holds strong referencess to byte buffers, so if map is not GC'd buffers are not as well

So is it bad practice? No, but bad practice is to hold your maps forever.

Consider using `WeakReference` for caching.

`Map<String,WeakReference<byte[]>>` will allow map values to be garbage collected despite map itself beeing non-collectable.

Comment: I had a similar idea, because I kill the reference to my map the byte array reference is rendered dubious for GCing. I will test what you recommended, thanks